# Mounting a s3 bucket as network drive on ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to mount a S3 bucket to a windows instance as a network drive on my EC2 system. Any ideas anyone.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to mount S3 to a Windows instance? That is not how S3 should be used.

Comment: What is the best way then? If you want network file storage.

Comment: At the moment, Amazon EFS is is ideal, but is only available for Linux (NFSv4). You could create a SMB share between Windows instances.

Comment: Ok Thank you @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it is not advisable.

Amazon S3 is an object storage system, not a filesystem. The correct way to use Amazon S3 is to put/get files using the S3 API (or with tools that use the S3 API, such as the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)).

If you *must* mount Amazon S3, you could use 3rd-party tools such as [CloudBerry Drive - Mount S3 as a Win Drive](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx). However, I would recommend that you test your solution before using it in production environment.

Comment: I generally agree with "not advisable," but doesn't [Storage Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html) support SMB mounts via File Gateway?

Comment: Ah! That would be an option!

Answer (score 6):

1. Install WinFsp http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/
2. Download rclone https://rclone.org/
3. Extract it for example here C:\Program Files\rclone
4. Once in the path, execute "rclone config" and follow the steps. Otherwise create this file C:\Users\David\.config\rclone\rclone.conf and fill it with you params. In my case:

   [minio]
   type = s3
   provider = Minio
   env_auth = false
   access_key_id = ...
   secret_access_key = ...
   endpoint = http://192.168.1.10:9000
   acl = public-read-write
5. Execute rclone (where Z will be the letter assigned to the mounted bucket, and 'bucketname' is your bucket's name):

   .\rclone.exe mount minio:bucketname Z: --allow-other --allow-root --dir-cache-time 0 --poll-interval 0 --vfs-cache-mode writes --write-back-cache --no-check-certificate --log-level INFO --progress

It works like a charm!

Comment: The WinFsp link leads to a 404.  I think it should be http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/rel ?

Comment: For the EC2 using a IAM role to access S3, you could refer to this:  
[s32win]
type = s3
provider = AWS
env_auth = true
region = ap-southeast-1
location_constraint = ap-southeast-1
acl = public-read-write

Comment: the default location seems to have changed to:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\rclone

my rclone.conf:
[s3]
type = s3
provider = AWS
access_key_id = xxx
secret_access_key = xxx
region = eu-central-1
location_constraint = EU
acl = public-read-write
bucket_acl = public-read-write